# Spring Data JPA Update Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm still looking for a update method in Spring's Data JPA to update a given **Object** persited in a relational database. I only found solutions in which I'm forced to specify some kind of UPDATE queries via @Query annotation (in comparison with @Modifying), for example:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.firstname = ?1, u.lastname = ?2 WHERE u.id = ?3")
public void update(String firstname, String lastname, int id);
```

For building the Query, I also have to pass single parameters instead of **whole Objects**. But that's exactly what I want to do (passing whole Objects).

So, what I'm trying to find is a method like this:

```
public void update(Object obj);
```

Is it possible to build such a update method based on Spring Data JPA? How must it be annotated?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the goal is to modify an entity, you don't need any update method. You get the object from the database, modify it, and JPA saves it automatically:

```
User u = repository.findOne(id);
u.setFirstName("new first name");
u.setLastName("new last name");
```

If you have a detached entity and want to merge it, then use the `save()`  method of `CrudRepository`:

```
User attachedUser = repository.save(detachedUser);
```

Comment: What if I am using findALL(). Do I need to loop for each User and then max multiple save calls ?

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal if you are in a `@Transactional`, selecting all, then modifying them is sufficient, no need to call explicit `.save()` or `.saveAll()` unless you have any detached (e.g. an entity that was not selected from db, or was detached manually) entity. End of the transaction will update each entity.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Will this update whole Entity (override whole), or will this just update the changed values.

Comment: This solution is good. But be careful, it will update all columns(even unchanged columns) that may costly or dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an Entity you do not need JPQL query(Optional). You can directly use (old version)findOne or (new version) findById to access data and make required modifications

Ex-  here approve (entity ) is updated.

```
Optional<User> user= Repository.findById(id);
Registration reg = reg.get();       
reg.setApproved("yes");
userRepo.save(reg);
```

And That's It.

Answer (score 0):

These answers aren't addressing the question, which is how to avoid all of the messy...

```
if (var1 != null) u.setVar1( var1 );
if (var2 != null) u.setVar2( var2 );
....
if (varN != null) u.setVarN( varN );
```

shenanigans.

So, in essence, the question involves how to merge an object. Unfortunately, JPA "merge" is a misnomer. It's re-attaching a detached object.

Have you tried using this scheme:

1. add jackson data-bind dependency
2. convert update object (source) to Map

Map<String, Object> sourceMap = objMapper.convertValue(source, Map.class);

3. remove null values using Java 8 streams
4. convert to-be-updated object (target to Map) as above
5. use new Java 8 Map merge method to update target with source, i.e.

targetMap.merge( ... );

6. then use objMapper to convert targetMap back to target type.

One caveat, now you have an updated entity that's not JPA-attached so you'd have to do a target.merge();