# Can I use a method name to create a Spring JPA update query?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Using https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details as a reference, I see how I can write a method in a repository without using the @Query annotation, i.e.
`List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);`

However, is there a similar way to write an update query through a naming convention?
i.e.
`void updateAllFirstNameByLastNameEqualTo(String lastname)`

[Spring Data JPA Update Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295688/spring-data-jpa-update-method) seems to suggest that there isn't.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case? Why do you need such an update query? In Spring JPA, as I understand, the expected approach with update is to get a bunch of records update them in the java code and just do `repository.saveAll(yourCollection)`. Will this approach work for you? Or?

Comment: I guess I was just enamored with the idea of being able to write the query in the same way as 'get' queries